# how to edit feathers generated services

Tags: javascript, node.js, feathersjs

I am quite new to the world of Nodejs, JS and featherjs. I have featherjs service created using the feathers generate service command. I want to edit and implement my own code logic, which it takes some input values then do some actions on them and save it the result and display on UI. So what can I do in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The Feathers documentation has a thorough [basics guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/readme.html) that shows how to get started without using the generator explaining all the basics concepts you need to know. It also explains how those things all fit together and how the generator sets them up.

If you are just starting out it is highly recommended to go through the basics guide and then the [chat application guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/chat/readme.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to open the basic guides examples available on the  documention but the link is not working. Is there any link which I can find the examples? And also I would appreciate if you could suggest me another examples like chat app which I can look through. Thanks

Comment: The link is https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/readme.html and it has all the information you should need. Once you worked through the guides you can find more examples at https://github.com/feathersjs/awesome-feathersjs